# mysql query to find actors acted in both films

Tags: mysql, sql

am trying to display actors acted in both films 
please help,it is not getting

```
SELECT actors.first_name,actors.last_name
FROM actors
LEFT JOIN films_actors
  ON actors.actor_id=films_actors.actor_id
LEFT JOIN films
  ON films_actors.film_id=films.film_id
WHERE films.title="ACADEMY DINOSAUR"
  AND films.title="ANACONDA CONFESSIONS"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`

```
SELECT actors.first_name,actors.last_name 
FROM actors 
JOIN films_actors 
  ON actors.actor_id=films_actors.actor_id
JOIN films 
  ON films_actors.film_id=films.film_id 
WHERE films.title IN ('ACADEMY DINOSAUR','ANACONDA CONFESSIONS')
GROUP BY actors.first_name,actors.last_name 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT films.title) = 2;
```

Comment: No need for `left` joins.

Comment: @lad2025, i have one doubt if we used IN condition then it will satisfy both films or if he acted in any of one,then it will true?

Comment: @user7441072 To satisfy condition that the play in both films you need `HAVING` part.

Comment: @lad2025 this giving correct result,any more simple way available?

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is probably unnecessary.  `COUNT(*)` should do.

Comment: @lad2025 are you there?